# SimpleExoPlayerView setDefaultArtwork image to fit inside the view

Tags: exoplayer

I'm using the `setDefaultArtwork` method to display an image for the `SimpleExoPlayerView` while the music is playing. How can I set the image to fit inside the view (`centerCrop`) ?

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

[Udacity says](https://classroom.udacity.com/nanodegrees/nd801/parts/443745fb-4ae4-4918-8ea1-6bf24e356c1d/modules/6cb81da9-d083-4721-a31b-4f435de9fedd/lessons/89b6a627-f121-498c-aa53-26304544b5f3/concepts/5d62a7ef-df84-43e1-8c64-882169c3044b):

> The issue with the above method is that it customizes the UI for every instance of SimpleExoPlayerView (and/or PlaybackControlView). For our use case, this doesn't matter since we only have one player view. However, if you need to customize individual instances, you can use a combination of the two above methods: use the player_layout_id attribute for a custom SimpleExoPlayerView, or the controller_layout_id for a custom PlaybackControlView and specify a custom layout file to override the layout for that specific instance.

So use the source and have a look at the [simple_player_view.xml](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/library/ui/src/main/res/layout/exo_simple_player_view.xml): it has a `ImageView` with id `exo_artwork`. Get that, and set its `scaleType`.

Answer (score -1):

```
val imageViewArtwork = playerView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.exo_artwork)
playerView.resizeMode = AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL
imageViewArtwork.scaleType = ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please provide some context on why this answers the OP's question?